# Cannot access to Kubernetes NodePort from other worker nodes except the pod's one

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I'm managing a standalone kubernetes (v 1.17.2) cluster installed on CentOS 7 with single API server and two worker nodes for pods.

One of the services is configured as a node port service however, I cannot reach the service from other nodes. I'm not very experienced in Kubernetes but, here is what I know

- `kube-proxy` is doing its job. Related port (31505) is open in every node (checked with `lost -i`).
- The service is up, I can access it just fine from the nodeport where the pod is running.
- Docker is configured with `no-iptables` option, and all firewall rules are managed by Kubernetes itself.

  - Stopping `kubelet` and `docker`, flushing all IPTables rules and forcing kubernetes to re-create them didn't solve the problem.
- All other services inside the Kubernetes cluster is working as expected.

For service details `kubectl get svc -o wide --namespace docker-registry docker-registry-deployment` is as follows:

```
NAME                         TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
docker-registry-deployment   NodePort   10.104.194.201   <none>        5000:31505/TCP   67d   app=docker-registry
```

Output of `kubectl describe svc docker-registry-deployment --namespace registry` is as follows:

```
Name:                     docker-registry-deployment
Namespace:                registry
Labels:                   app=docker-registry
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=docker-registry
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.104.194.201
Port:                     <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31505/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.65:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

At the current state, the pod cannot be accessed via its `Cluster IP:5000` from any node, but the `Endpoint:5000` is accessible and its responding as it should.

---

#### Update (2020-04-14)

There's no namespace problem for the service & the pods. They are in the same namespace.

I've updated the installations completely (incl. Docker and Kubernetes), and the problem has morphed. Now, **other nodes are also responding but, exactly after 63s**.

Will try to debug the problem and report back here.

Comment: could you post an output of your `kubectl get svc -o wide` for that service? And which k8s installation you are using? is it GKE/AKS/EKS/standalone/Minikube, etc?

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I've extended the question, hopefully this information helps.

Comment: can you access service from another node via Cluster_IP:5000 ? I'm trying to narrow down the root of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I've further edited the question.

Comment: It looks like a mismatch between Service created in a `--namespace docker-registry` that is supposed to pass traffic to the `app=docker-registry` that sits under `docker-registry-deployment` created for totally different namespace (`Namespace: registry`).  Could you please recreate either `svc` or `deploymenet` so they will sit in a same namespace and let me know ?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and let you now ASAP.

Comment: I guess, you may have issues with a network addon. Could you please add to the question/gist/paste_service output of the command `kubectl get nodes,ns,ds,deploy,pods,svc -A -o wide --show-labels` ? Please replace public IPs with a.b.c.X where X is the real octet number.

Comment: Thanks @VAS. I've found the problem and it's not the configuration of the K8S. I've added an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem at last.

It's a combination of flannel, complicated cni network structure and virtualization.

flannel is implementing its node to node routing network with `vxlan` and it's enabling offloading features on the vxlan device.

When offloading is enabled on a flannel device, `NodePort` accesses across nodes experiences a 63 second routing delay. The delay goes away when offloading is turned off with

```
ethtool --offloading tx off rx off flannel.1
```

My cluster is working on a Proxmox environment and the network cards are `virtio` devices. I don't think the problem is on the virtualization layer because I have another cluster on the same Proxmox node and everything is working fine. Since it's a production cluster, it's not updated this frequently.

So this one is marked as a flannel bug. Now I'll try to update flannel and see what happens.

**Update:** flannel is updated on this particular cluster and it's working like charm.

Comment: On CentOS following command works  `ethtool --offload flannel.1 tx off rx off`

Comment: Upgrading flannel works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the issue is that you can't reach app unless you are sending requests directly to the EndPoint.

It looks like the issue with the `Service` for me. Based on info you have provided, the Service was created in a `--namespace docker-registry` and is supposed to pass traffic to the `app=docker-registry` that sits under the `docker-registry-deployment` created for in different namespace (`Namespace: registry`).

Please note that the NodePort Srvices are supposed to be created in same namespace to the Deployment. If you reaaly need your service and app to be in different NSs, please check this thread on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221483/service-located-in-another-namespace).

I have created the Deployment and two services (one is in the same NS with the Deployment and another one in different NS).

My config looks like the below.
Namespaces

```
$ kubectl get namespaces
NAME                   STATUS   AGE
default                Active   108d
namespace-a            Active   48d
```

Services:

```
$ kubectl get svc --namespace namespace-a knp-hello-go-deploy-namespace-a
NAME                  TYPE       CLUSTER-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
knp-hello-go-deploy   NodePort   10.0.0.253   8180:30050/TCP   2m53s   app=knp-hello-go-app

$ kubectl get svc --namespace default knp-hello-go-deploy -o wide 
NAME                  TYPE       CLUSTER-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
knp-hello-go-deploy   NodePort   10.0.12.114  8180:32673/TCP   3h21m   app=knp-hello-go-app
```

I ran 2 GKE nodes. So I checked the node my pod is on and logged to another one.

Check via CLUSTER-IP

```
gke-node-mnnv:~$ curl 10.0.12.114:8180/test
Hello from ServerGo. You requested: /test 

gke-node-mnnv:~$ curl 10.0.0.253:8180
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.0.253 port 8180: Connection refused
```

Check via GKE-Node External IP:

```
gke-node-mnnv:~$ curl GKE_NodeIP:32673/test
Hello from ServerGo. You requested: /test

gke-node-mnnv:~$ curl GKE_NodeIP:30050/test
curl: (7) Failed to connect to GKE_NodeIP port 30050: Connection refused
```

Hope that helps! )

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The problem has evolved a bit. I'm updating the problem to reflect current situation.

Comment: It is better to revert changes and creating a new topic in such a case. Because now all the answers are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You have to have the UDP communication protocol open for the nodes communication.

Long answer: The issue was with the VXLAN tunnels, I'm using AWS for the environment, and I only allowed all TCP between nodes, not UDP, so communication between workers using VXLAN was not working.

After updating the security group, everything is working as expected.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/521295)

Comment: @Swisstone thanks for pointing out this! Just did it.